# Having trouble running a file with vs code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-cli

I'm new to coding with c# and looking for a little help

I have set up c# with visual studio code and in the terminal trying to use `dotnet run` but when i do it comes up with this:

> visual studio code cannot find program to run or pass the path to the
>   project using --project

I'm in the right file location but it cant seem to find the file. Any ideas.

I have tried the `--project` but it comes up with red writing and error and things.

Comment: "i tried the --project but it comes up with red writing and error and things." Include those red writing and errors, it might be relevant

Comment: Consider pressing F5 instead, at least until you figured out where stuff is located.

Comment: I know where the file is located but i cant get vs code to recognise that file. here is the errors (At line:1 char:3
+ --project
+   ~
Missing expression after unary operator '--'.
At line:1 char:3
+ --project
+   ~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'project' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator)